# React - existing page gets not found when refreshed

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I got stuck to the following situation in `React 18`. I have defined two components as in: `AppLayout` and `AddEvent`.

My `App.tsx` file looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppLayout from "../views/layout/AppLayout";
import './App.css';
import AddEvent from "../views/event/AddEvent";

const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<AppLayout />}/>
                <Route path="/events/add" element={<AddEvent />}/>
            </Routes>
        </Router>

    )
}

export default App;
```

In `AppLayout.tsx`, I have a button that allows me to navigate to `AddEvent` component:

```
<Space wrap>
  <Button type="primary" onClick={() => navigate('/events/add')}>Add new event</Button>
</Space>
```

When I run the app and land to the homepage, I'm able to navigate to my second page via the button. Tho, when refresing the `AddEvent` page, I get an empty page and the following error:

> GET http://localhost:8080/events/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not
> Found)

and

> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/events/main.js'
> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME
> type checking is enabled.

However, if I change the link to the `AddEvent` page from "/events/add" to "/events-add" I am not getting this error anymore and I can even refresh the page. Although I solved the issue, could anyone explain why is this happening? Many thanks.

Comment: The basic gist is that the root index.html file should be returned/served for all page requests into the app. How are you building and serving/hosting the app locally?

Comment: @DrewReese - "npm start" and using webpack. Not Vite/Parcel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding the following lines within `webpack.config` solved the issue:

```
output: {

  publicPath: "/",

},
```

As per the documentation of `webpack` [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#root), the above setting allows you to specify the base path for all the assets within your application.